# How to parse this XML and search for particular key value

Tags: php, xml

I have the following xml content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodResponse>
   <params>
      <param>
         <value>
            <array>
               <data>
                  <value>
                     <array>
                        <data>
                           <value>
                              <string>Car</string>
                           </value>
                           <value>
                              <string>1</string>
                           </value>
                        </data>
                     </array>
                  </value>
                  <value>
                     <array>
                        <data>
                           <value>
                              <string>Plane</string>
                           </value>
                           <value>
                              <string>2</string>
                           </value>
                        </data>
                     </array>
                  </value>
                  <value>
                     <array>
                        <data>
                           <value>
                              <string>Boat</string>
                           </value>
                           <value>
                              <string>3</string>
                           </value>
                        </data>
                     </array>
                  </value>
               </data>
            </array>
         </value>
      </param>
   </params>
</methodResponse>
```

I would like to retreive the number `3` only knowing the data `Boat`

Here is what I have done :

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$arr_response = $xml->params->param->value->array->data->value->array->data;
foreach ($arr_response as $key => $value) {
    if($key == "Boat"){
        echo "Found !";
        echo "$key -> $value";
    }else{
        echo "Not found";
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Not found
```

Comment: You have a typo here `foreach ($arr_res as $key => $value) {` arr_res must be arr_response?

Comment: Please enable proper PHP error reporting during development, then PHP has a chance to alert you to such mistakes on its own already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're dealing with xml, it's simpler to just use xpath:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
$boat = $xml->xpath('//data//value[string="Boat"]/following-sibling::value/string');
echo $boat[0];
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: @executable Trust me on this - it's definitely worth getting very familiar with xpath.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DomDocument` as in

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($data);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($xpath->query("//data[./value[1]/string[contains(text(), 'Boat')]]") as $boat) {
    echo $boat->getElementsByTagName("string")[1]->textContent;
}
```